# ITestResult getTestName() returns null despite of set test name by @Test(testName = "sth")

Tags: java, testng, listener

I set the test name in my test class using annotation: @Test(testName = "sth") and I need to get it from Listener class which implements ITestResult. Method getTestName() returns null but according to http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/ITestResult.html#getTestName-- should returns the string.

Am I doing sth wrong? Is it possible to get the string set in @Test(testName = "") from Listener class?

Answer (score 0):

`getTestName()` may return `null` in some case. Check [no regression test from TestNG](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/test/java/test/name/NameTest.java) if you want more details.
Depending on your needs, you'll find the 2 other ways to find test names.

Note: Only TestNG versions after 6.9.10 have this behavior.