# ITestResult.getTestName() in TestNG listener returns testname = null despite of setting name @Test(testName="Browser") on test method

Tags: selenium, testng

How to get the custom testName of the test in the listener?

TestDemo.java

```
@Test(testName = "Browser", description = "This is browser test", priority = 1)
public void launchTest() throws IOException {

System.out.println("I am in the test");
               }
```

Listener class

```
ListenerDemo.java

//some code

 public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {

        System.out.println(result.getMethod().getDescription()); //return dexcription as expected
        System.out.println(result.getMethod().getPriority()); //return priority as expected


        //Already Tried options but none of them worked

        System.out.println("Name "+result.getName()); //returns Name = launchTest
        System.out.println("Name "+result.getTestName()); //returns Name = null
        System.out.println("Name "+ result.getMethod().getMethodName()); //returns Name = launchTest

        //I am expecting one of the statement should return Name="Browser"

      }
```

Already looked at [ITestResult getTestName() returns null despite of set test name by @Test(testName = "sth")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39897855/itestresult-gettestname-returns-null-despite-of-set-test-name-by-testtestnam) but this doesn't provide any useful answer

I am using TestNG version 7.1.0.

Answer (score 2):

After some research, I found out this and it worked for me

```
public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {

     Method method = result.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod();
     Test test = method.getAnnotation(Test.class);
     String testname = test.testName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me...

public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {

```
      Method method = result.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod();
         Test test = method.getAnnotation(Test.class);
         String testname = test.testName();
      System.out.println(testname+" started");
  }
```

Comment: Looks like exact copy of OPs answer...